# The box "contacts" is already open and of type Box<Contact> when trying to access Hive database in flutter

Tags: database, flutter, flutter-hive

I initialized box database in main as follow

```
void main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    final appDocumentDirectory = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Hive.init(appDocumentDirectory.path);
    Hive.registerAdapter(ContactAdapter());
    runApp(MyApp());
}
```

then I open box in the material app by using FutureBuilder plugin as follows:

```
  FutureBuilder(
      future: Hive.openBox<Contact>('contacts'),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
          if(snapshot.hasError){
            return Text(snapshot.error.toString() );
          }
          return ContactPage();
        } else {
          return Scaffold();
        }
      }
    ),
```

and inside ContactPage()

I create this:-

```
  ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: Hive.box<Contact>('contacts').listenable(),
                builder: (context,Box<Contact> box,_){
                  if(box.values.isEmpty){
                    return Text('data is empty');
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: box.values.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context,index){
                        var contact = box.getAt(index);
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(contact.name),
                          subtitle: Text(contact.age.toString()),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                },
               )
```

when I run the application I get the following error

> ```
> The following HiveError was thrown while handling a gesture:
> The box "contacts" is already open and of type Box<Contact>.
> ```

and when I tried to use the box without opening it, I got error mean the box is not open.

Do I have to use box without opening it inside ValueListenableBuilder?
But then I have to open same box again in the different widget to add data on it.

Answer (score 5):

Its a simple explanation actually:
1. It only occurs when your box has a generic type like

`Hive.openBox<User>('users')`
2. So once you call `Hive.box('users')` without specifying the generic type this error occurs. 
**THATS EVERYTHING**.

**SOLUTION**
`Hive.box<User>('users')` at each call :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm jumping on this thread because I had a hard time trying to figure out how to deal with the deprecated WatchBoxBuilder while using the resocoder's Hive tutorial, and a google search led me here.

This is what I ended up using:

main.dart:

```
void main() async {
  if (!kIsWeb) { // <-- I put this here so that I could use Hive in Flutter Web
    final dynamic appDocumentDirectory =
        await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Hive.init(appDocumentDirectory.path as String);
  }
  Hive.registerAdapter(ContactAdapter());

  runApp(child: MyApp());
}
```

and then ContactPage() (note: it's the same as OP's):

```
Widget _buildListView() {
  return ValueListenableBuilder(
    valueListenable: Hive.box<Contact>('contacts').listenable(),
    builder: (context, Box<Contact> box, _) {
      if (box.values.isEmpty) {
        return Text('data is empty');
      } else {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: box.values.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var contact = box.getAt(index);
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(contact.name),
              subtitle: Text(contact.age.toString()),
            );
          },
        );
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you are trying to open the box inside `FutureBuilder`. If somehow it tries to rebuild itself, it will try to open the box which is already opened. Can you try to open the box after you register the adapter like:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final appDocumentDirectory = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(appDocumentDirectory.path);
  Hive.registerAdapter(ContactAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<Contact>('contacts');
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

And instead of `FutureBuilder` just return `ContactPage`

Answer (score 0):

In main.dart file :

```
future: Hive.openBox('contacts'),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
          } else {
            return ContactPage();
          }
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
```

In ContactPage:

```
return WatchBoxBuilder(
box: Hive.box('contacts'),
builder: (context, contactBox) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: contactBox.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final contact = contactBox.getAt(index) as Contact;
      return ListTile(
        title: Text(contact.name),
        subtitle: Text(contact.number),
        trailing: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
              onPressed: () {
                contactBox.putAt(
                  index,
                  Contact('${contact.name}*', contact.number),
                );
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: () {
                contactBox.deleteAt(index);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  );
},
```

);

It's OK to open the box in future call..

Comment: Just a note that WatchBoxBuilder has been deprecated in favor of ValueListenableBuilder.