# Flutter: The method 'listenable' isn't defined for the type 'Box' (using Hive)

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to read the contents of a Box using [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive), following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61719563/11625692) SO comment, but I get the following error:

> The method 'listenable' isn't defined for the type 'Box'

The code in question is:

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: Hive.openBox<Contact>('testBox'),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: Hive.box<Contact>('contacts').listenable(),
          builder: (context, Box<Contact> box, _) {
            if (box.values.isEmpty) {
              return Text('data is empty');
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: box.values.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var contact = box.getAt(index);
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(contact.name),
                    subtitle: Text(contact.age.toString()),
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        );
      },
    ),
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
hive: ^1.4.1+1
hive_flutter:
  git:
    url: git://github.com/hivedb/hive.git
    path: hive_flutter
```

What I am trying to do is list the content of the box when the screen loads. I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong - any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The solution: hive_flutter.dart needs to be imported first

`import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';`

Comment: Any suggestions on if the IDE says that import of `hive_flutter` is unused, and the `.listenable()` still throws the 'The method 'listenable' isn't defined for the type 'Box'.' error?

Comment: @ZachSmith, I solved that by importing both packages for hive and hive_flutter:  Import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

Answer (score 2):

Get the Most Upgraded Version of Hive, (currently it is) `hive: ^2.0.4`
Get the Most Upgraded Version of Hive_Flutter (currently) `hive_flutter: ^1.0.0`

In your Working Space Kindly Import them all

```
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
```

And You are good to Go to use, Box, Value-Listenable, Builder... etc.

Answer (score 1):

After using @MrJax's answer, if you get error like: **'The method 'listenable' isn't defined for the type 'Box'** , you should import both hive packages:

```
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
```

and assign *Box* type for **ValueListenableBuilder** widget like this: **ValueListenableBuilder<Box<*Contact*>>**