# Using Hive.box("user") throws the error The box "user" is already open and of type Box<User>

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I know this question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63660799/hiveerror-the-box-user-is-already-open-and-of-type-boxuser), but the solution doesn't help me. according to the hive doc, an opened box can be called like this `Hive.box('myBox');` when I try this in my code I get the error

```
The box "user" is already open and of type Box<User>.
```

anyone has an idea why this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem and the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60257233/the-box-contacts-is-already-open-and-of-type-boxcontact-when-trying-to-acces/67993801#67993801) proposed by Ray Zion works perfectly for me.

If you opened a hive box using generic **await Hive.openBox`<`String`>`('user_api')**, you need to use it later using generic **Hive.box`<`String`>`('user_api')**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
void stuff() async {
  //Hive.init('somePath') 

  var box = await Hive.openBox('user');

  box.put('name', 'David');
  
  print('Name: ${box.get('name')}');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem after migrate flutter null safety.
Set box object as non nullable. Error is disappear.
Wrong code:

```
late Box<User?> userBox;
Hive.box<User?>(HiveBoxes.userBox);
```

Correct:

```
Box<User> userBox = Hive.box<User>(HiveBoxes.userBox);
```