# Flutter - HiveError: Box is Already Open

Tags: flutter, textinput, box, flutter-hive

I am wanting to write user input into a box to store it.

I am getting the error **`The box "user_api" is already open and of type Box<String>.`**

I only opened it in the `main()` function and then closed it in the `_API_Page_State`

I am confused how I keep running into this problem. Can anyone help? Thanks.

(Input anything into the TextInput bar.)

**My Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';



Future<void> main() async {

  // HIVE SETUP---------------------------------------------
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(directory.path);
  await Hive.openBox<String>('user_api'); // Initially Opens Box on App Start

  await Hive.initFlutter();

  // HIVE SETUP---------------------------------------------                      *LATER: Set up Encrypted Box for the API Key. Set Up Unencrypted Box for other information.*

  runApp(API_Page_());
}



class API_Page_ extends StatefulWidget {
  const API_Page_({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _API_Page_State createState() => _API_Page_State();}

class _API_Page_State extends State<API_Page_> {

  @override
  void dispose() {
    Hive.box('user_api').close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  final TextEditingController _apiKeyController = TextEditingController();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Indietools Login'), backgroundColor: Color(0xFF7E57C2),),
        body: Center(child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              label: Text('API Key'),              
            ),
            controller: _apiKeyController,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Text('Store in Box');
              final api_key_input = _apiKeyController.text;
              var box = Hive.box('user_api');
              box.put('API: ', api_key_input);
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
            Text('Retrieve API in Box');
            var box = Hive.box('user_api');
            String data = box.get('API');
            Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: data,
              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16.0
            );
          })
        ],
          )
        ),
    );}}
```

Comment: Try by moving the line ```await Hive.initFlutter();``` above ```await Hive.openBox<String>('user_api'); ``` .

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60257233/the-box-contacts-is-already-open-and-of-type-boxcontact-when-trying-to-acces/67993801#67993801) proposed by Ray Zion works perfectly for me. The solution is the same as Jake B. commented above.

If you opened a hive box using generic **await Hive.openBox`<`String`>`('user_api')**, you need to use it later using generic **Hive.box`<`String`>`('user_api')**.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the Hive specs:
https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/basics/boxes?id=type-parameter-boxltegt

When calling openBox:

> ...It is important that you provide the same type parameter to Hive.box(). You cannot open the same box multiple times with different type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to insert `<String>` inside of `var box = Hive.box<String>('user_api');`

So the fix was: `var box = Hive.box<String>('user_api');`